# how to show a popup when page load in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

My project angular version:

Angular CLI: 9.0.0-rc.7

I want to show a popup when the page loads.

Is`ngoninit` is run only one time when page loads?

When I log in and then come to the dashboard page why does the popup not open?

The popup does not load. It gives an error in the browser console:

> **DashboardComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of undefined
>       at DashboardComponent.push../src/app/views/dashboard/dashboard.component.ts.DashboardComponent.ngOnInit**

**dashboard.component.cs:**

```cs
import { ModalModule, ModalDirective } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';

export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit
{
    @ViewChild('primaryModal') public primaryModal: ModalDirective;

    ngOnInit(): void {

        this.primaryModal.show();
     }
```

**app.module.ts:**

```
import { ModalModule,ModalDirective } from 'ngx-bootstrap';

NgModule({

 ModalModule.forRoot()


  ],
```

dashboard.component.html

```
<div bsModal #primaryModal="bs-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-primary" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" (click)="primaryModal.hide()" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="primaryModal.hide()">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

model.directive.d.ts

```
   ngOnInit(): void;
    /** Allows to manually toggle modal visibility */
    toggle(): void;
    /** Allows to manually open modal */
   public show(): void;
    /** Allows to manually close modal */
    hide(event?: Event): void;
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Try moving the `show()` call into the AfterViewInit [life-cycle hook](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-sequence).

Comment: @R.Richards You should make that an answer, as it is most likely the problem (or at least it is the main problem).

Comment: @R.Richards thanks my problem is solved.